Confused with Isolation Forest
Let say, I have the anomaly detection (unsupervised learning) dataset with 10 observations (two features). The datasets is like below:

After executing the model, following are the results (anomalies scores):

The observations which have score as -1 are anomalies. I have a question about isolation forest or I may not understand how it works correctly.
How isolation forest learns(loss function) while training the data? How it make sure that anomalies detected by model are actually the anomalies? For example - in above results the observation got scores as -1 could not be the anomalies then how we make sure the results are accurate because in case of unsupervised learning we don't have any target variable means there is no way to calculate errors. So, what would be minimized?
Can anyone please explain to me how it works and provide an example?

Have you looked at the sci-kit learn documentation page? There is not loss function that is used, instead the Mahalanobis distance is used to determine the distance of an observation to the distribution (which is in turn used to determine how likely the observation is to be an outlier).

cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/78545402/10495893

@BenReiniger could you please help me to understand the concept?

This strikes me as too broad for the stack exchange q&a format: you're asking roughly how unsupervised learning works at all, as well as how isolation forest works. Can you narrow the question down to, say, specific parts of the sklearn docs that @Oxbowerce linked?

@BenReiniger I know how isolation forest works, the only thing I want to understand how it optimizes the error? Based on Sklearn doc which @ Oxbowerce linked, how Mahalanobis distance is used to determine error?
